# How to show main window after hiding it from a dialog window in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm displaying mainwindow in one function with this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Engine engine;
    MainWindow w(&engine);

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Then in mainWindow I hide it and display dialog window with this code:

```
this->hide();
SomeDialog x;
x.setModal(true);
x.exec();
```

And then in the new SomeDialog window code I want to do something like this:

```
this->close();
parentMainWindow.show();
```

I think it would be possible by passing the parent MainWindow object to the constructors but I wonder whether there is some other option. Is there?

Comment: Why not put `show()` after `x.exec()`?

Answer (score 1):

`show` is a *slot* of `QMainWindow`. You can bind it to the *signal*s `accepted` and `rejected` of your dialog or whatever signal you plan to emit.

See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qml-qtquick-dialogs-dialog.html#accepted-signal), [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qml-qtquick-dialogs-dialog.html#rejected-signal) and [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qwidget.html#show) for further details.